# Managing git based deployments from within parent git repository

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have a parent directory that contains a bunch of related projects. Some of these projects are apps deployed to heroku which uses a git based mechanism to deploy apps. The result is that I end up with git repositories within the parent git. This can be quite confusing when working across different branches. What are the best practices to manage such an environment?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to properly modularize your projects, different projects belongs in different repos. For your needs, different deployments to Heroku belong in different repos, and there's no reason to aggregate them in *another* repo, which is plain wrong in git.

A rule of thumb I like to use goes by subdomains, anything that will live in a subdomain (i.e. deployed to a different environment) can easily be a separate repo/project.

Comment: What you said would be ideal but I need to use private repositories on github.com. Each new repository has a cost associated with it. I am looking for options other than moving each project to different repositories if that makes sense.

Comment: Then your problem is a cost efficiency problem, not programming related. Use http://bitbucket.org it has free private repos.